# What is the good format for temperature in SwiftUI TextField?

Tags: swiftui, temperature

I need to create a TextField with input value for temperature that the user wants to convert.

The code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

private final class TempConverterViewState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var temperatureInput = Measurement(value: 0, unit: UnitTemperature.celsius) }


struct TempConverterView: View {
    @StateObject private var state = TempConverterViewState()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Value", value: $state.temperatureInput, format: .measurement(width: Measurement<UnitTemperature>, numberFormatStyle: Decimal))
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Neither initialization, nor calling the variable throw any errors. The error is thrown in `var body: some View` line and it reads:

```
Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report
```

Do you perhaps see what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I have the exact same problem with Measurement<UnitPower> (for Watts). I just filed it as radar FB9914736, if you want to duplicate it.
For now I've fallen back to a good old `Int`, which works using `format: .number`

Comment: Yeh, using number myself, @Cyrille, but then when you have several conditions to check, you have to type each of them and this becomes quite a nightmare...